# vertical align with logo img inside navigation unordered list

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I'm building a navigation. The structure is some unordered lists floated left. The 1st line item though contains an image element and I cannot seem to align it within the UL vertically. This is tricky to explain so I have created a js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/JmjzU/

Any pointers on how to place the img in the middle of the containing UL, both vertically and horizontally without resorting to playing around with padding would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you though about setting it as a background-image with css?

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful but I already have a background image on that element - a 1px wide column separator. It seems to accept only one of the other. Also, I'd like the logo to be click-able with an <a> element anchored to the homepage.

Answer (score 0):

I found an unclosed style in your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JmjzU/1/

It was here and it changes the display quite a bit:

```
header img {
    display: block;
}
```

I changed the fiddle a bit for visual reference: http://jsfiddle.net/JmjzU/3/

Can you describe where you want your image to be in relation to the menu, nav area and everything else?

How is this? http://jsfiddle.net/JmjzU/4/

Comment: thanks for the comment - looks like that was a leftover from me fiddling in firebug after copy/pasting. I'd highlighted the background in red so I as I could see the element.
Anyway, I'm trying to find a way to position the img vertically center so that it is inline with the "design" line item. How would I do that?

Comment: @Doug Firr By inline with the design LI what do you mean? Same bottom, top, middle?

Comment: middle, so that it is in between the blue lines at the top and bottom